# Each input values into each <span> or <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of each input and put it in the span tag below without using ID's or classes. It's easy if I use classes or Id's. But I need to be able to use it without those. I need each input values put into each span tag. I have two but it will be more in actuality.

Thanks in advance.
any help is appreciated

below is my fiddle

```
var input = $('input:text');
$(input).each(function(){
  values = $(this).val();
});
$('b').each(function(){
   $(this).html(values); 
   console.log(values);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LB76/3/

Comment: And where is the HTML, "below" can mean anything ?

Comment: Post the related code, not just a fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, just juggle the `index`.

**jQuery**

```
$('input:text').each(function(i){//get index for each input
    var tx = $(this).val();//get value for this input
    $('b').eq(i).html(tx);//print value on output with same index
});
```

Which can easily be expanded to update irt, as you can see [**in this fiddle...**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/8943U/)

Answer (score 0):

First, set a counter variable `i` to `0`. The loop through each `<b>` element and increment `i` as we go through each. Populate the `<b>` element with the value of the input at index `i`.

```
function run() {
    var inputs = $('input:text');

    var i = 0;
    $('b').each(function(){
        $(this).html(inputs.eq(i++).val()); 
    });
}
```

**Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LB76/6/)**

You're being somewhat vague in your question, so please clarify if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thank You Evan. This is exactly what I was looking for. and sorry for the vagueness in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through ieach input and then each output. This is assuming that you have exactly the same number of input fields and spans to show the values.

Here is the code:

```
var input = $('input:text');
var values = new Array();
$(input).each(function (i) {
    values[i] = $(this).val();
});
$('b').each(function (i) {
    $(this).html(values[i]);
    console.log(values[i]);
});
```

**Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LB76/12/):**